# Chrome has stopped saving my passwords

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Does anyone know how to sort out Chrome. It has suddenly stopped asking and storing my usernames and passwords.  Everything is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the  link given  below to manage your website passwords.

Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.

Select Settings.

Click Show advanced settings.

Adjust your password settings in the "Passwords and forms" section:

Select "Offer to save passwords I enter on the web" if you want Google Chrome to prompt you to save your password every time you sign in to a new website.

Check this link for more details.

[LINK](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en)